# Save pandas data frame as csv on to gcloud storage bucket

Tags: python, gcloud, google-cloud-dataproc

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import gc
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np
import sys



APP_NAME = "DataFrameToCSV"

spark = SparkSession\
    .builder\
    .appName(APP_NAME)\
    .config("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled","true")\
    .getOrCreate()

group_ids = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]

dates = ["2016-04-01","2016-04-01","2016-04-01","2016-04-20","2016-04-20","2016-04-28","2016-04-28","2016-04-05","2016-04-05","2016-04-05","2016-04-05","2016-04-20","2016-04-20","2016-04-29"]

#event = [0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0]
event = [0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0]

dataFrameArr = np.column_stack((group_ids,dates,event))

df = pd.DataFrame(dataFrameArr,columns = ["group_ids","dates","event"])
```

The above python code is to be run on a spark cluster on gcloud dataproc. I would like to save the pandas dataframe as csv file in gcloud storage bucket at gs://mybucket/csv_data/

How do I do this?

Answer (score 6):

You can also use this solution with Dask. You can convert your DataFrame to Dask DataFrame, which can be written to csv on Cloud Storage

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas
df # your Pandas DataFrame
ddf = dd.from_pandas(df,npartitions=1, sort=True)
ddf.to_csv('gs://YOUR_BUCKET/ddf-*.csv', index=False, sep=',', header=False,  
                               storage_options={'token': gcs.session.credentials})
```

storage_options argument is optional

Comment: you have a typo in the last line. Should be `ddf.to_csv`

Answer (score 3):

So, I figured out how to do this. Continuing on from the above code, here is the solution:

```
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()  

from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlCtx = SQLContext(sc)
sparkDf = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(df)    
sparkDf.coalesce(1).write.option("header","true").csv('gs://mybucket/csv_data')
```