# Google Dataproc with Jupyter - Downloading files generated by notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-dataproc

We're using Google Cloud Dataproc for quick data analysis, and we use Jupyter notebooks a lot. A common case for us is to generate a report which we then want to download as a csv.

In a local Jupyter env this is possible using `FileLink` for example:

```py
from IPython.display import FileLinks
df.to_csv(path)
FileLinks(path)
```

This doesn't work with Dataproc because the notebooks are kept on a Google Storage bucket and the links generated are relative to that prefix, for example `http://my-cluster-m:8123/notebooks/my-notebooks-bucket/notebooks/my_csv.csv`

Does anyone know how to overcome this? Of course we can `scp` the file from the machine but we're looking for something more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

To share report you can save it to Google Cloud Storage (GCS) instead of local file.

To do so, you [need](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53148394/upload-pandas-dataframe-to-gcp-bucket-for-dataproc#comment93273001_53165332) to [convert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45495108/save-pandas-data-frame-as-csv-on-to-gcloud-storage-bucket/45495969#45495969) your Pandas DataFrame to Spark DataFrame and write it to GCS:

```py
sparkDf = SQLContext(SparkContext.getOrCreate()).createDataFrame(df)
sparkDf.write.csv("gs://<BUCKET>/<path>")
```

Comment: Thanks, this will work but not what I'm looking for. It's actually better to use Dask for this. But I was looking for something more convenient without conversions

Comment: In this case, you may want to try to override URL prefix by specifying `url_prefix` and/or `result_html_prefix` parameters in [`FileLinks`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html?#IPython.display.FileLinks) call.

Comment: I've tried toying with it a bit but couldn't find a way to fix it. Do you know what prefix or html_prefix I should use?

Comment: I would guess that you need to specify master hostname as a prefix, but anyway you will need to make it accessible to internet by opening up firewall rules which is insecure or ssh into the network which is not convenient. That's why the best option would be to use GCS to share your reports.