# How to export dataframe to csv in bucket on google cloud

Tags: python, file-io, google-cloud-platform, export-to-csv, stringio

I'm trying to export a pandas dataframe to a csv file in a bucket on my google cloud storage, but the following code obviously isn't working for me:

```
my_df.to_csv(StringIO(file_io.FileIO('gs://mybucket/data/file.csv', mode='w+')))
```

How should this be rewritten? I'm getting the following error:

```
unbound method write() must be called within FileIO instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Apologies if the answer is obvious, but I'm just starting to learn python.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save pandas data frame as csv on to gcloud storage bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45495108/save-pandas-data-frame-as-csv-on-to-gcloud-storage-bucket)

Comment: Is your CSV of a memory holdable size?  If yes, you can apparently write a new object to GCS from a string from python.  If your data is too large, you can write it to a local file and then upload the file from API.  Don't confuse GCS for a file system.

Comment: I was specifically attempting to determine how to use StringIO and FileIO to export a file to gcloud storage bucket. None of the other solutions offered here, which I perused, offered a solution. I was successful in using these to import a csv on gcloud to a dataframe, so I assumed it wouldn't be too complicated to do the same in the other direction. I did manage to get gcs to work, so I'll post how I did so below for anyone else who might be wondering.

Answer (score 2):

Importing a file from gcloud to dataframe works when I code thus:

```
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import file_io
from pandas.compat import StringIO
import pandas as pd

def read_data(gcs_path):
   file_stream = file_io.FileIO(gcs_path, mode='r')
   data = pd.read_csv(StringIO(file_stream.read()), names=['various', 'column', 'names'])
   return data

my_df = read_data('gs://mybucket/data/file.csv')
```

But I haven't been able to reverse the process.

GCS has worked for me, however:

```
import google.cloud.storage as gcs

client = gcs.Client()
bucket = client.bucket('my-bucket')
blobs = list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix='data/'))

my_df.to_csv('tmp.csv')
local_tmp_path = ('tmp.csv')
target_blob = bucket.blob('data/file.csv')
target_blob.upload_from_file(open(local_tmp_path, 'r'))
```

Comment: For what are you using `blobs`?

Answer (score 0):

You can save your csv file in your VM and then use `gsutil` to save it on your bucket.

Python:

```
my_df.to_csv("data.csv")
```

Shell:

```
gsutil data.csv gs://my_bucket/
```